# For-loop doesn't complete all iterations

Tags: vb.net

I have problem with this - I try to send broadcast SMS using AT Commands in my system. After that the SMS content will be stored in my database. My store content SMS function works well. I can store all my SMS content that I send, but the send function just sends message to my first data on my datagridview. 
Please help me to deal with this - I posted my code below

```
    Private Sub ButtonKirim_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonKirim.Click
    Dim noPel As String
    Dim isiPesan As String = ""
    Dim tgl As Date = Now.Date

    Dim strReplace(2) As String
    Dim strIsi(2) As String

    Dim tagBulan As String = "<bulan>"
    Dim tagtagihan As String = "<tagihan>"
    Dim tagLokasi As String = "<lokasi>"
    Dim pesanKirim As String = ""

    My.Settings.SettingPesan = RichTextBoxPesan.Text
    My.Settings.Save()

    'Label4.Text = isiPesan
    For pelanggan As Integer = 0 To DataGridViewKirimPesan.RowCount - 1

        'mengirim pesan/send message
        noPel = DataGridViewKirimPesan.Rows(pelanggan).Cells(3).Value()


        strReplace(0) = tagBulan
        strReplace(1) = tagtagihan
        strReplace(2) = tagLokasi

        strIsi(0) = DataGridViewKirimPesan.Rows(pelanggan).Cells(4).Value
        strIsi(1) = DataGridViewKirimPesan.Rows(pelanggan).Cells(5).Value
        strIsi(2) = DataGridViewKirimPesan.Rows(pelanggan).Cells(6).Value
        isiPesan = RichTextBoxPesan.Text
        For i As Integer = LBound(strReplace) To UBound(strReplace)
            isiPesan = isiPesan.Replace(strReplace(i), strIsi(i))
        Next

        SendMessage(noPel, isiPesan)

        ''menyimpan pesan keluar ke sms_terkirim/this query store my content SMS to table
        Dim sqlSmsKeluar As String = "INSERT INTO sms_terkirim (`tgl_sms`,`id_pelanggan`, `isi_sms`) VALUES ( NOW()," & DataGridViewKirimPesan.Rows(pelanggan).Cells(0).Value & " , '" & isiPesan & "');"
        cudMethod(sqlSmsKeluar)
        MsgBox(sqlSmsKeluar)

        'ProgressBarKirimPesan.Increment(1)

    Next
    'MsgBox("Pesan Sukses Terkirim")
    '        Catch ex As Exception
    '    MsgBox("Pesan Gagal Terkirim" + ex.Message)
    'End Try
    '    End If


End Sub
```

and this code is AT Command to send message

```
Public Sub SendMessage(ByVal NomorPelanggan As String, ByVal IsiPesan As String)

    If SerialModem.IsOpen() Then
        With SerialModem
            .Write("AT" & vbCrLf)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            .Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            .Write("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & NomorPelanggan & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            .Write(IsiPesan & vbCrLf & Chr(26))
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox("Modem Belum Tersambung")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try to use the debugger to check what are the values inside your loop code? Often the time spent using the debugger repays itself immediately

Comment: thanks for answering, how to use the debuger ? i am really newbie with this thing

Comment: @LukmanHakim are you using visual studio.. I believe you click on the left to make "breakpoints", and click debug rather than just run.. and hover over variables

Comment: yes im using visual studio,

Comment: where should i take the break point ?

Comment: If you use the standard keyboard shortcuts, move your cursor on the initial for-loop instruction then press F9 now run your code as usual and when the line is ready to be executed the Visual Studio IDE will stop the execution at the line. Now you can look at the variables and their values just moving the mouse over the variable or check the contant in the Local Window. Continue your code step by step pressing F10.

Comment: On addition to @Steve comment you can also add a watch on something. When the breakpoint hits you can highlight the code you want and right click and add watch. When that code gets hit and ran you will get the output...